# php extension not loading in MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, protocol-buffers

i am using MAMP server i am trying load a extension in my php but i am getting error, i tried everything but i cant make it load :(.

i am using mac os and php 5.6.7

that line is for the extension: extension=protocolbuffers.so

i inserted in: Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/conf/php.ini

i inserted too in: /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.6.7/php.ini

and still not loading.

i run that php file called: extension.php to see if my extension is loading.
so i got the error so i definitely not loading the extension:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ci-match/extension.php on line 3

```
    <?php
if (!extension_loaded('protocolbuffers')) {
    if (!dl('protocolbuffers.so')) {
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

i use too php
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>

but i cant see my extension there, how can u guys help me to load that extension?

can you guys help me with that? thank you.

Comment: I am interested to know how did you get compiled binary? I need to use as mentioned here: https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/Dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that the [`dl()`-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) has been removed completely from a number of SAPIs, it usually is disabled for security reasons.
I'm not sure whether the disable will result in an undefined function error or in a security error of some kind. Guess you'll have to find out.

You can control access to it using the [`enable_dl`-directive](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.enable-dl) in `php.ini` and by making sure safe mode is not enabled.

As for your attempts to load the extension:
I WOULD run a .php file with `phpinfo();` in. That will tell you which .ini files are being loaded and where the extension directory is.

You can then use that information to add it in the correct location. Chances are that your MAMP loads from a weird location.

It's very hard to diagnose issues like that remotely.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is not my php code, the php code was a test to see if the extension is loading. followed by here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

i just wanna know how can make the extension run on my php ini. :) thank u